# Custom action in ribbon open in dialog on top of another dialog

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, custom-actions

Has anybody succesfully been able to open a dialog from a custom action on the ribbon on top of another dialog?

The use case that I have a list, which already opens in dialog. On the dispform.aspx i have a custom action in the ribbon. When I click the action an edit form from another lists open in dialog. However in does not open op top of the exsisting list, but rather replaces the existing dialog.

Comment: how did you create the custom action in the ribbon?

Comment: Using SharePoint designer. I would prefer not messing with the xml.

Answer (score 0):

You could add custom action to open modern dialog by JSOM.

Here is my test sample code.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        //$(document).ready(function() {
        //    SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(AddCustomUserAction, "sp.js");
        //});
        //var oListItem;

        function AddCustomUserAction() {
            //Get the client context and list object
            var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("dialog");
            //Get the custom user action collection and add the user action
            var customUserAction = list.get_userCustomActions().add();
            //Set the location of the user action
            customUserAction.set_location('CommandUI.Ribbon.DisplayForm');//CommandUI.Ribbon.ListView
            //Add the properties for the custom action
            var userActionExtension = '<CommandUIExtension xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">' + '<CommandUIDefinitions>' + '<CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.ListForm.Display.Manage.Controls._children">' + '<Button Id="Ribbon.Documents.New.RibbonTest" ' + 'Command="CustomDialog" ' + 'Sequence="0" ' + 'Image16by16="/_layouts/images/NoteBoard_16x16.png" ' + 'Image32by32="/_layouts/images/NoteBoard_32x32.png" ' + 'Description="DialogTest" ' + 'LabelText="DialogTest" ' + 'TemplateAlias="o1"/>' + '</CommandUIDefinition>' + '</CommandUIDefinitions>' + '<CommandUIHandlers>' + '<CommandUIHandler Command="CustomDialog" ' +
            'CommandAction="javascript:SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog({ url: &#34;/SitePages/Forms/AllPages.aspx?isdlg=1&#34;, title: &#34;Custom Dialog&#34;,showClose: true });" />' + '</CommandUIHandlers>' + '</CommandUIExtension>';
            //Add the command UI extension and update the custom user action
            customUserAction.set_commandUIExtension(userActionExtension);
            customUserAction.update();
            //Load the client context and execute the batch
            context.load(list, 'UserCustomActions');
            context.executeQueryAsync(function () {
                console.log("Custom User Action added successfully to ribbon.");
            }, function (sender, args) {
                console.log(args.get_message());
            });
        }
    </script>
    <input id="Button1" onclick="AddCustomUserAction()" type="button" value="button" />
```

[image]
Referenced thread.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-ribbon-custom-action-using-javascript-object-model-in-sharepoint-2016-and/

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble getting it to work. Can I ask if your solution has been tested on SP 2016? In the console I can see, it is supposed to have loaded the custom action, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Oh well I figured out i can just add the javascript in the link part in SPD:
javascript:SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog({ url: "MY LINK", title: "Custom Dialog",showClose: true });

Works like a charm - thanks a lot!